# Can machine learning extract two source signals, given a mixed signal?

Tags: machine-learning, source-separation

I have two signals from two sources at a given condition and I have a mixed signal at the same condition that I know is coming from those same two sources. Is it possible to extract the source signals from that mixed signal using machine learning? I am attaching the stft plots of the two source signals where the fundamental is at 2.25 MHz and there are some harmonics. The difference between them is that source 1 has subharmonic and ultraharmonic while source 2 doesn't have them. I tried the 'Cocktail party source separation using deep learning in matlab' but I think it didn't work.
[image: source 1]
[image: source 2]

Comment: It seems that there's not much information difference for any algorithm to work on.

Comment: Yes a properly trained model can separate sources, check [demucs](https://github.com/facebookresearch/demucs) for instance.

Comment: Do you want an answer to the _general_ question in your title, or the _specific_ question that the question text seems to imply?  In general, the answer to "can machine learning perform some arbitrary task in information processing?" the answer is "it depends on the task".  ML will only have a _chance_ to perform some task if that task is theoretically possible.  You haven't given enough detail in your question for anyone to determine whether that chance might exist.

Comment: Basically, if the source at 2.25MHz can be extracted from _just_ the sub- and super-harmonics of the source, then yes, ML can almost certainly do this.  If it cannot be thus extracted, then there's no way to add that source with one that's a pure tone and then separate them out from the resulting sum.

Comment: @TimWescott, so if I add these two sources then the mixed signal will have sub and ultraharmonics. But I know that these are coming from just one source. Are you saying that there is no way to extract that source using ML?

Comment: @NASRINAKTER what he's saying is: if two different causes can lead to the same result, then **no** algorithm, be it classical, or ML, or anything else, can tell you which cause a result had. So, Tim is asking you whether that's the case.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, there should be subtle differences between the two source signals like I have shown in the plots. That is all I have to work on.

Comment: I'm not saying you *can't* -- I'm giving you the one condition where you **might**.  Do your signals meet that condition?

Comment: @NASRINAKTER "there should be": is there?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes there is. Can you please suggest in this case what I should do?

Comment: @TimWescott, yes the signals meet the condition.